# How to iterate over an array of dynamic type in C# 4.0?

Tags: c#-4.0

Hi I have an array of dynamic type which i want to iterate through. But when i say arrayObject.lenght, i get following error:

'object' does not contain a definition for 'length' and no extension method 'length' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found

how do i iterate over the array?

[Update]

I post a custom json object using jquery ajax and i have written a model binder for untyped JSON. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can show some code of what exactly you are doing?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
foreach (dynamic item in cartJsonObject)
{
   // code here
}
```

I was trying with `for` loop and `foreach` using `var` type. Changing it to `dynamic` solved it.

Comment: To make this work you may need to add a Reference to "Microsoft.CSharp".

Answer (score 0):

This error very likely means that what you have is not an array but another collection - `IEnumerable` would be my best guess. You can use the `Count()` extension method provided by Linq to retrieve the number of elements.

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Count' and no extension method 'Count'