# using dynamic type in C# and accessing elements array from JSON (dynamic type and DynamicJsonObject)

Tags: c#, json, dynamic

i have a json string taken from a 3rd party API.
however this third party API, we dont know the exact JSON definitions of it and has a lot of attribute, we just know that they have the information that we need on it

here is an example

```
{
  "exp": 1670979934,
  "iat": 1670979634,
  "auth_time": 1670979634,
  "jti": "86a4610c-9e9a-473f-9cc0-0959aa779702",
  "iss": "http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/ScopicSoftware",
  "aud": "account",
  "sub": "2874bbca-e34b-44f0-8ca7-cfc57708a124",
  "typ": "Bearer",
  "azp": "keycloakdemo",
  "realm_access": {
    "roles": [
      "default-roles-scopicsoftware",
      "offline_access",
      "uma_authorization"
    ]
  },
  "resource_access": {
    "keycloakdemo": {
      "roles": [
        "admin"
      ]
    },
    "account": {
      "roles": [
        "manage-account",
        "manage-account-links",
        "view-profile"
      ]
    }
  }
...
...
}
```

as I said we dont own and dont have the exact information of the JSON except for the output, so we cannot just do Json.Deserialize and pass a model object to it. (or can we based on limited info?)

we want to acccess the "resource_access"->"keycloak_demo" and the "roles" array

what i tried was to use the dynamic type in C# instead

```
dynamic dataX = Json.Decode(responseString);
```

and i can access the information thru

```
   var demo = dataX.resource_access.keycloakdemo;
```

it returns an a variable with type DynamicJsonArray.
However, i cannot iterate to it using ordinary for loop or Enumerator, it crashes.

So what is the proper way of doing this given We dont have the model definition?

Comment: `resource_access` is an object not an array, it contains a property named `keycloakdemo` which contains an array named `roles`

Comment: To iterate dynamic type: [iterate-over-an-array-of-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565619/how-to-iterate-over-an-array-of-dynamic-type-in-c-sharp-4-0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use code like this

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(json);

string[] roles = jsonParsed.SelectToken("resource_access.keycloakdemo.roles")
                                                          .ToObject<string[]>();

foreach (string role in roles)
{

}
```

Comment: this one worked as well, thanks!